# How to calculate the no of clock cycles in RISCV-clang

Tags: clang, llvm-clang, riscv

I am using riscv64-unknown-elf-clang, "clang version 5.0.0" to compile my code and then run it with **"spike" and "pk"** . I need to calculate the no of clock cycles the program takes. I used **"__builtin_readcyclecounter()"** or normal **"clock()"** to calculate clock cycles but none seems to work.

The below code works with **riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc** but not with ***riscv64-unknown-elf-clang***

```
#define read_csr(reg) ({ unsigned long __tmp;asm volatile ("csrr %0, " #reg : "=r"(__tmp));__tmp; })
#define CSR_CYCLE 0xc00
#define CSR_TIME 0xc01
#define CSR_INSTRET 0xc02
#define CSR_MCYCLE 0xb00
```

Then from the main program I called

```
long cycles;
cycles=read_csr(cycle);
```

Comment: Have you compared the generated assembler code?

Comment: The code doesn't even compiles with riscv64-unknown-elf-clang . It shows an error stating unrecognized mnemonic

Comment: Should `cycles=read_csr(cycle);` read `cycles=read_csr(CSR_CYCLE);`?

Answer (score 0):

Clang 5.0 is just too old for the `csrr` pseudo-instruction, i.e. the pseudo-instruction support in Clang 5.0 is incomplete. Support for `csrr` [was added in 2018](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blame/ae0852b7ac129c7f59d619ca75b7e1e7e7f3b9b4/lib/Target/RISCV/RISCVInstrInfo.td#L549) while Clang 5 was released in 2017.

Either you upgrade to a newer Clang version or you work around this issue by expanding `cssr` (*control-and-status-register-read*) to `cssrs` (*control-and-status-register-read-and-set*) directly in your code, i.e.

```
csrr dst, csr => csrrs dst, csr, x0
```

Note that there are even more specialized pseudo-instructions for reading performance related counters such as `rdcycle dst`, and `rdtime dst` etc. Of course, they also expand to `cssrs`, but might be more convenient to use for some use cases.

Also, with a complete toolchain, you can also use the symbolic constants `cycle`, `time`, `instret` etc. (instead of `0xc00`, `0xc01`, `0xc02` etc.) directly in you assembler code.

Example that lists the equivalent ways to read out the cycle count:

```
extern __inline
    unsigned long 
    __attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
rdcycle(void)
{
    unsigned long dst;
    // output into any register, likely a0
    // regular instruction:
    asm volatile ("csrrs %0, 0xc00, x0" : "=r" (dst) );
    // regular instruction with symbolic csr and register names
    // asm volatile ("csrrs %0, cycle, zero" : "=r" (dst) );
    // pseudo-instruction:
    // asm volatile ("csrr %0, cycle" : "=r" (dst) );
    // pseudo-instruction:
    //asm volatile ("rdcycle %0" : "=r" (dst) );
    return dst;
}
```

I don't think that it's worth it using the C-pre-processor (CPP) for reading the different CSRs.

Note that even with `asm volatile` the compiler [is free to reorder](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blame/ae0852b7ac129c7f59d619ca75b7e1e7e7f3b9b4/lib/Target/RISCV/RISCVInstrInfo.td#L549) the different inline assembler statements to each other and to other instructions. For example, in

```
unsigned long a = rdcycle();
int r = i * i;
unsigned long b = rdcycle();
```

the second CSR access might be reordered before the multiplication or even the before the first one.